# SpringMVC JQuery WebCam plugin

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am working on a **SpringMVC** application. This application is a form, the user takes their picture with the [Jquery WebCam Plufin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). I have the webcam working and i am able to take the picture, however i now need to write the image to the database or upload it to the server.

I would like to insert into the database.I am wondering do i upload to the server first before i insert into the database? I am unsure how to approach this. Can someone guide me on this and the best approach to be taken

**Code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        document.createElement("canvas");

        $("#canvas").hide();

        $("#camera").webcam({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                useMicrophone: false,
                mode: "callback",
                swffile: "resources/swf/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
                quality:85,

                onSave: saveCB,
                onCapture: function () {
                    $("#camera").hide();
                    webcam.save();
                    $("#canvas").show();
                },

                debug: function (type, string) {
                    $("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
                }

        }); 



        $('#upload').click(function () {
            webcam.capture();
            return false;
        });

        $('#retake').click(function () {
            $("#canvas").hide();
            $("#camera").show();
            return false;
        });


        window.addEventListener("load", function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

            if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
                image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
            }

            }, false);
});

    <div id="tab1" class="divGroup">
            <form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="POST" commandName="citizens" action="citizen_registration.htm">
                <div id="divRight" class="mainDiv">             
                    <div class="divGroup" id="divCharInfo"> 

                        <label id="status"></label>                             
                        <div id="camera"></div>

                        <div><p><canvas id="canvas" name="photo" height="240" width="320"></canvas></p><form:errors path="photo" class="errors"/></div>
                        <input  id="upload" type="button" value="Take Photo">
                        <input  id="retake" type="button" value="Re-Take Photo">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you still need an answer on this one. By the way, you are using jscam_canvas_only.swf, that does not support the "save" mode. Try again after moving to jscam.swf...